# Segmentation Fault while running VASP 5.4.1

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, mpi

So we're trying to compile VASP 5.4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Following similar installation steps described here:
[How to compile VASP 5.4.1 for Linux Debian using the GNU compiler](http://www.ivofilot.nl/posts/view/31/How+to+compile+VASP+5.4.1+for+Linux+Debian+using+the+GNU+compiler). However, when testing the vasp executables (vasp_std, etc..), the program terminates with a segmentation fault - invalid memory reference error.

The makefile.include that we currently have is:

```
# Precompiler options
CPP_OPTIONS= -DMPI -DHOST=\"IFC91_ompi\" -DIFC \
         -DCACHE_SIZE=4000 \
         -DMPI_BLOCK=8000 -DscaLAPACK -Duse_collective \
         -DnoAugXCmeta -Duse_bse_te \
         -Duse_shmem -Dtbdyn

CPP        = gcc -E -P -C $*$(FUFFIX) >$*$(SUFFIX) $(CPP_OPTIONS)

FC         = mpif90
FCL        = mpif90

FREE       = -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none

FFLAGS     =
OFLAG      = -O2
OFLAG_IN   = $(OFLAG)
DEBUG      = -O0

LIBDIR     = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
BLAS       = -L$(LIBDIR) -lblas
LAPACK     = -L$(LIBDIR) -llapack
BLACS      = -L$(LIBDIR) -lblacs-openmpi -lblacsCinit-openmpi
SCALAPACK  = -L$(LIBDIR) -lscalapack-openmpi $(BLACS)

OBJECTS    = fftmpiw.o fftmpi_map.o  fftw3d.o  fft3dlib.o \
         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.a
INCS       =-I/usr/include

LLIBS      = $(SCALAPACK) $(LAPACK) $(BLAS)

OBJECTS_O1 += fft3dfurth.o fftw3d.o fftmpi.o fftmpiw.o chi.o
OBJECTS_O2 += fft3dlib.o

# For what used to be vasp.5.lib
CPP_LIB    = $(CPP)
FC_LIB     = $(FC)
CC_LIB     = gcc
CFLAGS_LIB = -O
FFLAGS_LIB = -O1
FREE_LIB   = $(FREE)

OBJECTS_LIB= linpack_double.o getshmem.o

# Normally no need to change this
SRCDIR     = ../../src
BINDIR     = ../../bin
```

After running:

```
mpirun -np 8 /home/<user>/VASP/vasp.5.4.1/bin/vasp_std
```

the program runs for some time then terminates with a number of segmentation fault messages (the last time I ran it it gave 8 of them!):

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F62EE595777
#1  0x7F62EE595D7E
#2  0x7F62EDA95CAF
#3  0x4DE3EA in __nonl_MOD_spher
#4  0x637E84 in __msphpro_MOD_sphpro
#5  0xC1E013 in MAIN__ at main.f90:?
```

Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: VASP is a commercially supported code. Perhaps, you should address your problem to [the VASP team](http://www.vasp.at/).

Comment: Thanks. We're contacting them.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it should have nothing to do with your VASP compilation, it depends on a certain setting in your Linux system. I'm not sure if this works, before each of your tasks at the command line please type:

```
ulimit -s unlimited
```

Comment: How can you be sure that the problem is in stack overflow and not in some bad memory access?

Comment: In fact you are right, the possibility exists. But with VASP, if there is some incorrect memory access, the program will end at the beginning and it is very uncommon to encounter such an error report at the end of the run.

Comment: Quite the opposite. Stack evorflow errors are very common at the very start of the program. General invalid memory accesses can hapoen at any time.